# Retrieve data in edittext from mysql database in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

My app has an An Activity which retrieves the data from MySql in to edit texts on clicking a button

1. Activity code , php code and layout code is being attached .

There is no error in the compile time and there is some error in the logcat .. The dialog opens up , keep running for seconds and then dismisses but the edit text fields are not filled up by the data from MySQL.

2. The name of the table in the MySQL is services_provider_details1 which contains respective columns (    Service_Provider_ID,Name,Address, Pincode, Phone_Number,DOB,Aadhar_Number,Price,Specialisation,Status ).

Here is my code

```
public class Update extends  Activity {


EditText  et_spid,et_fullname,et_address,et_sid,et_aadhar,et_dob,et_phone,et_pincode,et_price,et_status,et_spl ;
Spinner spinner;
Button update_button, go;
String spid;

InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null ;
String myJSON;
JSONArray peoples = null;



    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
    public static  final String TAG_PROVIDERS = "providers";
    public static  final String TAG_SPID = "spid";
    public static  final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
    public static  final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    public static  final String TAG_PINCODE = "Pincode";
    public static final  String TAG_PHONENUMBER = "Phone_Number";
    public static  final String TAG_AADHARNUMBER = "Aadhar_Number";
    public static  final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    public static  final String TAG_SPL = "spl";
    public static  final String TAG_STATUS = "status";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update);
          et_spid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_spid_insert);
          et_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_name_insert);
          et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_address_insert);
          et_pincode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_pin_insert);
          et_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_phone_insert);
          et_aadhar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_aadhar_insert);
          spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        et_price =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_sid_price);
        et_status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_sid_status);
        et_spl =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_sid_speacialisation); 
         update_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_update);
         go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_go);



        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                spid=et_spid.getText().toString();
                new go().execute();
            }
        });
        }

    class go extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog progress;
        String Url="http://192.168.2.7/myapp/update.php";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String res = "";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Update.this, "Loading Details",
                    "Please wait..", false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Url);
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("spid",spid));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }    
         try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
         catch(Exception e)
        {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     


        return res;

     }
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            myJSON = response ;
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
                peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);


             String Name=(c.getString("Name"));
                String Address=(c.getString("Address"));
                String Pincode=(c.getString("Pincode"));
                String Phone_Number=(c.getString("Phone_Number"));
                String Aadhar_Number=(c.getString("Aadhar_Number"));
                String price=(c.getString("price"));
                String spl=(c.getString("spl"));
                String status=(c.getString("status"));


                et_fullname.setText(Name);
                 et_address.setText(Address);
                 et_pincode.setText(Pincode);
                 et_phone.setText(Phone_Number);
                 et_aadhar.setText(Aadhar_Number); 
                 et_price.setText(price);
                et_spl.setText(spl);
                et_status.setText(status);




            } 
            }
             catch(Exception e)
            {

                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
progress.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

3. PHP code

```css
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
mysql_select_db("myapp");  



     $spid = $_POST['spid'];


    $sql="select * from services_provider_details1 WHERE Service_Provider_ID='$spid' " ;
    $r=mysql_query($sql);
    $result = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        array_push($result,
array('Name'=>$row[1],'Address'=>$row[2],'Pincode'=>$row[3],'Phone_Number'=>$row[4],'Aadhar_Number'=>$row[6],'price'=>$row[8],'spl'=>$row[9],'status'=>$row[10]));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysql_close();

?>
```

Logcat of the programme when run

```css
04-10 13:24:57.105: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:57.145: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:57.145: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:57.225: W/System.err(1859): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-10 13:24:57.296: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
04-10 13:24:57.296: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
04-10 13:24:57.306: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
04-10 13:24:57.325: W/System.err(1859):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
04-10 13:24:57.325: W/System.err(1859):     at com.example.homerun.Update$go.onPostExecute(Update.java:197)
04-10 13:24:57.345: W/System.err(1859):     at com.example.homerun.Update$go.onPostExecute(Update.java:1)
04-10 13:24:57.357: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-10 13:24:57.376: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-10 13:24:57.376: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-10 13:24:57.396: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 13:24:57.396: W/System.err(1859):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 13:24:57.406: W/System.err(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-10 13:24:57.426: W/System.err(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 13:24:57.436: W/System.err(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 13:24:57.436: W/System.err(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 13:24:57.465: W/System.err(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 13:24:57.465: W/System.err(1859):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 13:24:57.475: I/Choreographer(1859): Skipped 113 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 13:24:58.285: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-10 13:24:58.285: W/Trace(1859): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

And Please also tell me that Is XML File required?

Comment: You should do Jason parsing in post execute method . Ui should not be updated from background thread

Comment: First, all `mysql_` commands are deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and they have been **removed** in PHP 7.0.0. I would advise to switch to PDO or, alternatively, MySQLi.

Comment: Also, does your server return the correct data? There are several things that could go wrong, both on the server and on the client. I would first use a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to verify that the server returns what I expect. Once the server part is working, I would focus on the client part.

Comment: @Arjan  
Thanks Arjan .. Yeah please help I will be highly obliged .. Its been so frustrating for me now .. Its like android ..shot me down .. Thanks .. I have added what it looks like on server side.

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks for the reply yes I have done some change in the json thing and parsing is done in post execute method now , but still nothing comes in edit text and getting some error in log cat too which is updated here . So please help me out .

Comment: @Arjan  Yes I have done some changes suggested by you in the php file and removed the REQUEST thing and now the PhP works perfectly but still getting  some error in log cat and    I have done some change in the json thing and parsing is done in post execute method now , but still nothing comes in edit text and the updated code and logcat  is updated here . So please help me out .

Comment: there is some problem with your json response

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be the server side php code, more specifically this section:

```
$spid=$_REQUEST['spid'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$address=$_REQUEST['address'];
$pin=$_REQUEST['pin'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
$aadhar=$_REQUEST['aadhaar'];
$price=$_REQUEST['price'];
$spl=$_REQUEST['spl'];
$status=$_REQUEST['status'];
```

You do not check whether or not the keys exist in the array `$_REQUEST` and when a key does not exist it will trigger a notice. That is expected behaviour.

To fix that, you should update each line so it will check whether the key exists and only access it if it is present:

```
$spid = isset($_REQUEST['spid']) ? $_REQUEST['spid'] : null;
```

In PHP 7 (which you are not using, since you are using `mysql_` functions), you would be able to do the same in a shorter syntax:

```
$spid = $_REQUEST['spid'] ?? null;
```

Since you use `$spid` in the `WHERE` clause of your query, you may want to make sure that field is present. That also requires an explicit check.

Comment: Yes I have done some changes suggested by you in the php file and removed the REQUEST thing and now the PhP works perfectly but still getting  some error in log cat and    I have done some change in the json thing and parsing is done in post execute method now , but still nothing comes in edit text and the updated code and logcat  is updated here . So please help me out .